# Prove inequality of big powers without calculating them

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

How do you prove that $10^{10} > 2 \cdot 9^{10}$ ? I checked with calculator and it's true but I can't prove it without calculating these powers. Use of logarithms also require calculator to actually check that and I can't find other methods that could help me with this.

Comment: Divide both sides by $9^{10}$ and check if $(\frac{10}9)^{10} \geq 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
10^{10} - 9^{10} & = (10-9)(10^9 + 10^8 \cdot 9 + \;\cdots\; + 10 \cdot 9^8 + 9^9) \\
 & \gt 9^9 + 9^8 \cdot 9 + \;\cdots\; + 9 \cdot 9^8 + 9^9 \\
 & = 10 \cdot 9^9 \\
 & \gt 9 \cdot 9^9 \\
 & = 9^{10}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'm accepting this because this is actually the easiest. I totally forgot about this method. Thanks!

Comment: @Octothorp You're welcome. This happens to work because the inequality to prove was rather lax. The above does in fact prove the stronger $10^{10} \gt 2 \cdot 9^{10} + 9^9$, which itself is not a very tight inequality. The other answers are worth remembering, too, for closer cases where simple tricks may not always work.

Answer (score 6):

Use the binomial theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{10}9\right)^{10}&=\left(1+\frac19\right)^{10}\\
&=1+10\cdot\frac19+\binom{10}2\left(\frac19\right)^2+\ldots\\
&>1+10\cdot\frac19\\
&>2\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 4):

*Bernoulli's  inequality* is enough:
$$(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx\quad\text{for all}\enspace x>-1.$$
 $$\text{Thus}\hspace{5.5em}10^{10}=9^{10}\Bigl(1+\frac19\Bigr)^{10}\ge9^{10}\Bigl(1+\frac{10}9\Bigr)=9^{10}\Bigl(2+\frac19\Bigr)>2\cdot9^{10}.\hspace{5.em}\mbox{}$$